# bind-params not working can't find solution because i don't understand what it does

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**The problem:**

I had a very unsafe way to insert things into my database, so someone on stack here told me how to do it better. Thanks to that person! But there's a problem... The moment I want to insert the data I get this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

So I did a var_dump of my $stmt var and it puts out: NULL

**Here's the code:**

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_username', 'my_password', 'my_database');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

$nowDate=date("d/m/Y H:i:s");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO projecten (`user_ref`, `email_user`, `date_created`, `title`, `tweet`, `description`, `category`, `filename`, `invoice`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $gebruikerID, $email, $nowDate, $title, $tweet, $description, $category, $nameImage, $customUniqueId);

/* execute prepared statement */
  $stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

I've been on [This page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to check out more about the bind_param, but it doesn't work out that good...

Does someone know the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: In your query the invoice is missing a backtick.

Comment: @TheDrot You are a hero (if this works)

Comment: @TheDrot it didn't work.. :/

Comment: In order to fix the error you have to get the error message. Refer to the linked answer for the pointers.

Comment: how do I do that @YourCommonSense?

Comment: Obviously something is wrong with the query. What's the structure of projecten table?